# <SQL> How to add letter to result data

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is my query for monthly data.

```
select
  NVL(MONTH, 'SUM) MONTH
   , sum(A) AS A, sum(B) AS B
 from
  (
    select b.* 
        from TABLE  b
    where b.MONTH between '201305' and '201306'
  )
    group by ROLLUP(MONTH)
```

I get data like

```
 |  MONTH  | 

   201305

   201306
```

But I want the data to be named as below.

```
  |  MONTH  | 

 2013. 05 MONTH

 2013. 06 MONTH
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: the `grouping_Id` function gives you the level of aggregation. `nvl` that and not the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply using a `CASE` statement?

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN MONTH IS NULL THEN 'SUM'
  ELSE SUBSTR(NVL(MONTH, 'SUM'),1,4) || '. ' || 
       SUBSTR(NVL(MONTH, 'SUM'),5) || ' MONTH' END MONTH
   , SUM(A) AS A, SUM(B) AS B
FROM
  (
    SELECT b.* 
        FROM  b
    WHERE b.MONTH BETWEEN '201305' AND '201306'
  )
GROUP BY ROLLUP(MONTH)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12a99/1).

Comment: Come to think of it, it's not a date field considering how it's being compared :)  +1